# Regex need to includes the plus sign

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following problem with my regex.

I want to search a string between two strings.

The `datas` is like that:

```
var datas = "a='00-8'b='13-'a+='00-2'b+='3333'c='4'";
```

I try:

```
datas.match("a\+='(.*?)'");
```

I can't get the regex working due to the `+` sign.

Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a *String* into `match`, not a *RegExp*, perhaps you wanted

```
datas.match(/a\+='(.*?)'/);
```

Alternatively, you need to escape your backslash for the *String* so it can escape the `+` as a *RegExp*, i.e.

```
datas.match("a\\+='(.*?)'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the regex within forward slashes.

```
datas.match(/a\+='(.*?)'/g);
```

OR

Escape the backslash one more time, if it's enclosed within double quotes.

```
> datas.match("a\\+='(.*?)'");
[ 'a+=\'00-2\'',
  '00-2',
  index: 15,
  input: 'a=\'00-8\'b=\'13-\'a+=\'00-2\'b+=\'3333\'c=\'4\'' ]
> datas.match("a\\+='(.*?)'")[1];
'00-2'
```